# Viewport doesn't update when modifying geometry nodes with scripting

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Learning how to use blender python scripting and am editing some existing geometry nodes on an object. When I do so however, the viewport doesn't reflect the changes i've made. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. [Screen-recording of issue](https://imgur.com/a/Hm49g7Q)

Comment: can fix this by toggling into edit mode and back but surely theres a better way

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by calling `modifier.node_group.interface_update(context)`

```
context = bpy.context
modifier = context.active_object.modifiers['GeometryNodes']
modifier['Input_2'] = 5.0
modifier.node_group.interface_update(context)
```

Also note that `modifier['Input_2']` in this case is a floating point number, and you should use `5.0` instead of `5`.
(https://docs.blender.org/api/3.3/bpy.types.NodeTree.html#bpy.types.NodeTree.interface_update)

Comment: Have you tried setting `5` instead of `5.0` and got any weird behavior/error? Every time I test, integers work just fine and are converted to floats behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok, that was not the case when I tried it (Blender 3.3 and 3.5)
The input option disappears and when using `interface_update` it was set to 1.0 (default_value).

Comment: I just checked to be sure and you're right, in the case of setting geonode modifier values, must use the dot, thanks!

Comment: Is there a better way to set a geonode modifier value?
That would call the setter and convert the int into a float.
Because right now we access directly to the stored/internal value.